# Add items to array based on selection or set number

Tags: javascript

I've been experimenting with a Canvas for the first time and have a small game where obstacles randomly fly from the right to the left and the player on the left can move up and down to dodge them, score points for each dodge and it stores high scores.

I manually need to add obstacles to an array with a for loop to add them to a canvas at random x, y positions:

```
function ChooseRandom(min, max) { // random generator function
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

const obstacles = [ // array of obstacles to create using randomly generated positions
  {
    x: ChooseRandom(500, 2500),
    y: ChooseRandom(0, 500),
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  },
  {
    x: ChooseRandom(500, 2500),
    y: ChooseRandom(0, 500),
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  },
  {
    x: ChooseRandom(500, 2500),
    y: ChooseRandom(0, 500),
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  }
]

for (let i = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++) { // loop creating the obstacles using array
    const obstacle = obstacles[i];

    ctx.fillRect( // create obstacle
      obstacle.x,
      obstacle.y,
      obstacle.width,
      obstacle.height
    );
}
```

The more items in the array the more difficult it becomes (as there's more spawning in to avoid). Because each items uses the same code, is there a way to just type/set a number and it could populate the array with that many obstacle items in it?

Obviously this would save on code size but also I was thinking of adding a difficulty selection field, so if easy was selected it would only add maybe 6 obstacles on screen at any one time (6 items in the array), medium 12, hard 24 etc. So if there was away of populating the array with a number of duplicate items that can be generated from different set numbers, it would help in this situation.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to be able to set a number and then create the `obstacles` array containing that number of randomly generated obstacles? Are there any restrictions on the obstacles, e.g. that their positions can't overlap?

Comment: Hi ada, that's exactly correct yeah. I haven't figured out myself how not to let them overlap but to be honest it creates some interesting shapes to dodge sometimes when a few overlap so I'm not too bothered about them doing so. So it's fine if they overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```js
n = 6;
const obstacles = [];

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  const x = ChooseRandom(500, 2500);
  const y = ChooseRandom(0, 500);
  const obstacle = {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      width: 50,
      height: 50
  }
  obstacles.push(obstacle);
}
```

You can set `n` to whatever number of obstacles you want to generate, create an empty `obstacles` array and populate the array by generating a new obstacle on each iteration of the loop. This does not prevent overlap though.

Comment: Thanks you, this does seem really nice and clean and I can console log to see it build the 6 objects/items in the array, so I think it's working as needed. I just need to get it working correctly in my script to see and confirm but this seems like the answer, and I will return to mark it as the answer if so.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for that was easy enough to adapt into my code thank you. I had tried a .push() function before but I didn't get it working with the rest of the looping so this helped massively with my knowledge too.  Thanks and I've marked it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use Factory function with configuration and some default values to generate your obstacles:

```js
function ChooseRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function RandomObstacle({
  xMin = 500,
  xMax = 2500,
  yMin = 0,
  yMax = 500,
  w = 50,
  h = 50
} = {}) {
  return {
    x: ChooseRandom(xMin, xMax),
    y: ChooseRandom(yMin, yMax),
    width: w,
    height: h,
  }
}

let n = 3;

let obstacles = [];
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  // Using default values
  obstacles.push(RandomObstacle());
}
console.log(obstacles);

obstacles = [];
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  // Using custom configuration to override some of default values
  obstacles.push(RandomObstacle({xMin: 2000, h: 150}));
}
console.log(obstacles);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check out this answer with my code too